# Compiled VB6 EXE does nothing at all, but runs fine from the IDE?

Tags: ide, vb6

I found a strange problem between running the code in vb6 IDE and the compiled .exe. When I run my code via vb6 IDE everything works fine, there are no problems and the code executed correctly, but.. when I compiled the project, and run the .exe, **nothing happened**, the exe file doesn't run.

P.S. I want to note that when I open the vb6 IDE I don't run with administrator permissions. This seems a bit odd to me.
Any ideas?

Comment: One suggestion is to try to use Compatibility Mode on your compiled exe file (exe file in Explorer -> properties -> Compatibility tab, and try e.g. Windows XP or some other early version of Windows)

Comment: Reneat, thank you so much, i set compatibility with windows 8 and now everything works great!

Comment: Good that it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out it needed to set Compatibility Mode on compiled exe file. Navigate to exe file in Explorer -> properties -> Compatibility tab, and try e.g. Windows 8 or some other early version of Windows.

Comment: I have yet to come across a VB6 created executable where that is necessary, provided one doesn't do _"nasty"_ things like trying to access/write to folders that a non-privilegued user has no permission for. Setting Compat. mode to XP is more forgiving in that regard. But the better solution ofc is to figure out why that is even necessary.